# Chrome phishing warning on main

Tags: support, google-chrome, security

[image: Chrome phishing warning]

I just got a Chrome phishing warning on main for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741991/php-mysqli-dll-warning-in-linux-server

Is it just me, Chrome screwing things up or do you people have work to do?

The message in English:

> Known phishing site detected.
>   Google Chrome has denied the access to stackoverflow.com. This site is reported as phishing site.
>
> Phishing sites are designed to mislead you, so that you disclose your login credentials, password or other personal data. These sites occur as sites which you probably trust.

Comment: Hmm, no repro here. Not even for that particular page.

Comment: Looks like I only get it for that particular [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741991/php-mysqli-dll-warning-in-linux-server).

Comment: I would suppose it's not version specific, but what version are you on?

Comment: Reproed on Chrome here as well. (version 30.0.1599.101 m, location UK)

Comment: I'm currently on Versie 32.0.1687.2 canary Aura. But I have seen this before *cough cough php.net*. Where some people get the warning sooner then others.

Comment: BTW lol @ the instant no repro downvote for something that *might* need some attention :P

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome / OS X

Comment: I said, translate... :P

Comment: (Just as an aside: weird, Google somehow decided to change the look and feel of that page? I'm quite used to the styling of the screenshot from the question, but today I see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PeUat.png) in Chrome 30 on a Mac. Not an improvement.)

Comment: @PeeHaa - The link in your question is wrong I think? The one in your comment is different and is the one I repro-ed on.

Comment: The link in my question is edited in by @thiefmaster. I got in on the .dll question. I think thief got it on the other one.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Reproed here as well now. Took some time to catch up apparently.

Comment: sorry, typo when opening the link and since i got the warning there i never noticed the mistake. now there's the correect link

Comment: `status-repo` on Chrome 30.0.1599.66.

Comment: Wohoo! There is a phishing information about the site. For me its a Phishing Detected!

Comment: @ThiefMaster, did you miss a "did not" in *"since i got the warning there"*? If not, then did you get the same warning [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741319/android-action-bar-three-dots-not-displayed)?

Comment: Repro on Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m (Windows 7, EN, Southwestern US).

Comment: @Anna Why the untag? I and many others have reproed it...

Comment: @Doorknob No repro here, for one. For another, there's not much point in tagging this. [status-reproduced] is typically used for bugs that we're going to fix. There's nothing for us to do here.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue. Win7, chrome v30.0.1599.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not much we can do about this.

This is a false positive on the end of Google / Chrome.

Click the [report an error](http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?tpl=googlechrome_csd&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19741991/php-mysqli-dll-warning-in-linux-server&hl=en-US) link and submit a report for them. With enough of these, it will clear out.

It seems to be triggering on the existence of the text `php_mysqli.dll` on the page.

---

Update:

For what's it worth - the error has cleared up for me and webmaster tools doesn't have it reported as an issue.

Comment: How do you know what it is triggering on? (Just to be sure that there's no rogue ad in your system, which happened to be shown when Google indexed this... On the other hand: Google might not see those ads at all?)

Comment: @Arjan - I don't, not for certain. But that is an educated guess. As for ads - we are very careful with our ads and we do not target specific questions with them - if there were a rogue ad, more pages would be affected.

Comment: How are you so sure it is a false positive? Have you actually contacted google? You know what happened to php.net when they told everybody it was a false positive?

Comment: @PeeHaa, lucky difference is that *phishing* would probably just indicate some link to a bad site; if I recall correctly then on php.net *malware* was installed upon visiting?

Comment: As an aside: for *malware*, Google's Webmaster Tools provide more details, just for the site owner. (But then it also provides more details on the warning screen, so maybe things are different for phishing, and one cannot get more details.)

Comment: @Arjan thing is there is no outside link on that page. Neither has there been.

Comment: True, @PeeHaa. So then rogue ads are often a thing to look at. Also, in theory it *could* have been a link in the very first revision of the question, which was deleted within the 5 minute grace period, after Google already indexed it. But I agree with Oded that most probably it's just a false positive. So no php.net scenarios. ;-)

Comment: Call me paranoid, but when it comes to security issues I would like to know for sure.

Comment: @PeeHaa - that's fair. I am simply saying I can't see anything on the page that would trigger that.

Comment: This happens periodically, especially on questions that ask about virus-related or otherwise malicious code. Bit weird in this case, though, so I'm also in the "false positive" camp. (There's no repro on my end in Chrome 29.0.1547.76.)

Comment: Yeah - this seems to have cleared up on my side now.

Comment: @Anna, just in case it matters (like if phishing sites are reported in combination with IP addresses): still the same warning from Amsterdam.  (The page first loads, and *then* the warning is showed on top of it. That doesn't feel too helpful for cases where malware is distributed...) However, from the same computer, http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=stackoverflow.com nor http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=stackoverflow.com/questions/19741991/php-mysqli-dll-warning-in-linux-server show any problems. (API details at https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing)

Comment: @PeeHaa - nothing in webmaster tools

Comment: :-( That's not very useful. The warning is gone for me btw.

Comment: @PeeHaa - for what's it worth - we have had a number of such false positives on Chrome before. We have never found anything of substance.

Comment: No more repro for me